Law of large numbers result for largest component in Erdos-Renyi
Let $G(n,\frac{p}{n})$ be the Erdos-Renyi random graph with $n$ vertices. Let $C(n,p)$ be the size of the largest component. It’s is known that when $p<1$ then $C(n,p)$ is of order $log(n)$ with high probability. Is there also a LLN kind of result in this case i.e $\frac{C(n,p)}{log(n)} $ converges to some $c(p)>0$ for $p<1$ ?
Any references are appreciated. Thank you.

With apologies, I will switch the notation, to avoid writing $\frac pn$ for the edge probability (which is almost always $p$, and $p = \frac pn$ would be silly). Let's say we are looking at $G(n,p)$ with $p = \frac cn$, $0 < c < 1$.
The following summarizes Lemmas 2.10-2.12 of Frieze and Karoński's Introduction to Random Graphs:

With high probability $G(n,p)$ contains no components with more than one cycle.

With high probability there are $o(\log n)$ vertices in components that have a single cycle.

Let $\alpha = c - 1 - \log c$, and let $\omega$ be a quantity that goes to $\infty$ with $n$, but very slowly; in particular, $\omega = o(\log \log n)$. Let $T$ be the largest tree component of $G(n,p)$ (which, as we've just learned, is the largest component period). Then with high probability, $$\left|V(T) - \frac1\alpha\left(\log n - \frac52 \log \log n\right)\right| \le \omega.$$ (The idea with $\omega$ is that the speed of convergence hidden in that last "with high probability" statement may depend on how quickly $\omega$ grows.)


In particular, the desired constant is $\frac1\alpha = \frac1{c-1-\log c}$. (All logarithms are natural logarithms.)

See Lemma 2.12 here:
https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/BOOK.pdf
Essentially the limit you ask for is like $1/(p-1-\log p)$
(But you should use c, not p, since p is usually the notation for the edge probability)
